# Replacing only the last instance of a word in a string in freemarker

Tags: string, loops, indexing, freemarker

I'm trying to parse out the text that goes on a check. I need to replace the last 'y' and add 'pesos con' instead. I originally tried to split the string at the 'y' and join, but it turns out that there can be more than one 'y' when the written-out number has a 'y' like:

'cien mil seiscientos cincuenta y ocho y 01/100'

the desired result should be: 'cien mil seiscientos cincuenta y ocho pesos con 01/100'

I tried splitting the string at each character (?split('')) and then count from the end of the string to index where the second 'y' is because it should always be the same distance from the end of the string.

Then, I iterated over the split string as I copied over each character to a new string. If the index was equal to that of of the last 'y' (length-7) I added 'pesos con' to the new string instead of the element, 'y.' If the index wasn't that of the last 'y' i just copied over the character.

Unfortunately, the indexing doesn't appear to be working as expected because I can't seem to get it to print in with the 'pesos con' in the correct place. How can this be improved to implement this logic?

```
    <#function removeY>
    <#list records as check>
    <#assign str = ''>
    <#assign totalWordsArr = check.totalwords?split("")>
    <#list totalWordsArr as x>
    <#if x?index != x?length-7>
    <#assign str = str + " " + x + " ">
    <#elseif x?index ==x?length-7>
    <#assign str = " " + str + " " + 'pesos con '>
    </#if>
    </#list>
    <#return str>
    </#list>
   </#function>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with this solution:

```
<#assign x="cien mil seiscientos cincuenta y ocho y 01/100">
${x?keep_before_last(" y ")} pesos con ${x?keep_after_last(" y ")}
```

that brings the result you need:

```
cien mil seiscientos cincuenta y ocho pesos con 01/100
```